# ChangeDetection with datatable.net angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables, angular6

I am running into quite a few issues with the datatable component I wrote.

If I, for instance, delete a row from my datatable, the row is deleted, but my datatable loses all pagination functionality etc.

I have a feeling it is because my data is loaded after the datatable is instantiated.

I would like to instantiate the Datatable after my data has been fetched, and I am attempting to do the following:

```
export class DatatableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {
  dataTable: any;
  @ViewChild('dt') private dataTableRef: any;

  @Input() responseModelObservable: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.modelConfig = datatableConfig[this.modelTypeName];
    this.initializeColumns();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    // TODO: need to cleanup to cater for rerendering
    // this.tableBody.changes.subscribe(t => {
    //   if (this.hasRenderedTable !== true && this.tableBody.length !== 0) {
    //     this.initializeDtOptions();
    //     this.dtTrigger.next();
    //     this.hasRenderedTable = true;
    //   }
    // });
  }

  private initializeColumns() {
    this.responseModelObservable.subscribe(x => {
        ...

        //detect if data changed:
        this.cdr.detectChanges();

        //Initialize datatable:
        this.dataTableRef.DataTable();

      } else {
        this.hasData = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The above code throws the following Error:

> _this.dataTableRef.datatableConfig is not a function

How can I instantiate the `Datatable` after data has loaded?

Comment: Call `initializeColumns` from `ngAfterViewInit()` as opposed to `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @AmitChigadani Still loses sort order, and page quantity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datatable.net` does not work well with Angular. It does not bind the data. You have to rely on datatable.net event handlers such as:

```
datatable.on('init', () => {})
```

Hook into these.

https://datatables.net/manual/events#Listening-for-events

datatable.net is also not a responsive solution so you get all kinds of qwerkiness when you have too many columns.

A better solution would be to stop using datatable.net and use [devextreme](https://js.devexpress.com/) or [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com) where binding works and both of which have plenty of Angular specific examples.